# How to convert a black and white photo that was originally colored, back to its original color?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've converted a colored photo to black and white, and bolded the edges. Now i need to convert it back to its original color with the bolded edges. Is there any function in matlab which allows me to do so?

Comment: I think you cannot convet B/W image to color image...

Comment: If you have not saved the color data, there is no way to go back to its original state. Note that by converting it to B/W you are truncating 3 Values (probably RGB, depending on the color scheme) into one (Lightness)

Comment: However you can colorize an image with some kind of approximation, like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8214-gray-image-to-color-image-conversion) one

Comment: @dkk It would be called a `colormap`. @exxcellent: why don't you bold the edges on your colored image? Is there a reason to get rid of the colors? (other than colors don't exist in image processing 101)

Comment: Can you keep around a copy of the original image? Then you could multiply (or do something more complicated, I'm not an expert on image processing, color theory etc.) the original and gray-scale version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you remove the colour from an image, there is no possible way to automatically put it back. You're basically reducing a set of 16,777,216 colours to a set of 256 - on average each shade of grey has 65,536 equivalent colours, and without the original image there's no way to guess which it could be.

Now, if you were to take the bolded lines from your black-and-white image and paint them on top of the original coloured image, that might end up producing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to do is to use some filter over the B/W image and then use that with the original color. I suggest you convert your image to a color space with Lightness channel that suits your needs (for example L*a*b* if you need the ligtness to be uniformly distributed regarding human recognition of differences) and apply your filter only over the Lightness channel.